# Carrierwave / fog undefined method `gsub` for #<Array:0x000001067d4798>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, cloud, carrierwave

I am using fog and carrierwave to store images on a Rackspace Cloud files service.

When i try to upload an image (from a form), i get this error:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2631ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `gsub' for #<Array:0x000001067d4798>):
  app/controllers/things_controller.rb:8:in `update'

  Rendered /Users/marcoprins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered /Users/marcoprins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/marcoprins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/marcoprins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (23.0ms)
```

The error traces to the line where the record is saved.

Carrierwave: **v0.10.0**
Fog: **v1.30.0**
Rails: **v3.2.21**

I have tried so many things to fix this error, including building a brand new empty test app with rails **4.1.6** from scratch, and I am still getting the same error.

Here is my uploader:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  storage :fog

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png tiff)
  end
end
```

And my config/initializers/carrierwave.rb:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider:           'Rackspace',
    rackspace_username: '**********',
    rackspace_api_key:  '*********************************',
    rackspace_auth_url: Fog::Rackspace::UK_AUTH_ENDPOINT,
    rackspace_region:   :lon
  }
  config.fog_directory = '********',
  config.asset_host = 'https://********************-*******************************.ssl.cf3.rackcdn.com'
end
```

What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

## EDIT - stacktrace

```
fog (1.30.0) lib/fog/rackspace/core.rb:145:in `escape'
fog (1.30.0) lib/fog/rackspace/requests/storage/put_object.rb:32:in `put_object'
fog (1.30.0) lib/fog/rackspace/models/storage/file.rb:270:in `save'
fog-core (1.30.0) lib/fog/core/collection.rb:51:in `create'
carrierwave (0.10.0) lib/carrierwave/storage/fog.rb:261:in `store'
carrierwave (0.10.0) lib/carrierwave/storage/fog.rb:80:in `store!'
carrierwave (0.10.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/store.rb:59:in `block in store!'
carrierwave (0.10.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:17:in `with_callbacks'
carrierwave (0.10.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/store.rb:58:in `store!'
carrierwave (0.10.0) lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:375:in `store!'
carrierwave (0.10.0) lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:207:in `store_image!'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:424:in `block in make_lambda'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:221:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:221:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:215:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:215:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:103:in `save'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/validations.rb:51:in `save'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:21:in `save'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:268:in `block (2 levels) in save'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:329:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:199:in `transaction'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:268:in `block in save'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:283:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:267:in `save'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:232:in `block in update'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:329:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:201:in `block in transaction'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:209:in `within_new_transaction'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:201:in `transaction'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:230:in `update'
app/controllers/things_controller.rb:8:in `update'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionview (4.1.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:73:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
rack (1.5.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.3) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
rack (1.5.3) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
rack (1.5.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.3) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
rack (1.5.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
rack (1.5.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.3) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.3) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/Users/marcoprins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/marcoprins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/marcoprins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Show full error backtrace, please.

Comment: Please show your `things_controller.rb`

Comment: @MarekLipka [full error backtrace](http://pastebin.com/1WqZTGPg)

Comment: "This paste has been removed!"

Comment: Mmmm thats weird, i can still see it! But try this https://paste.ee/p/NaN0o

Comment: [things_controller.rb](https://paste.ee/p/3eLgz) @Aetherus